# Data not showing in angular table

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

I can't get the table rows to show, only the header will show ( [here you can see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgSrk.png) ).
The problem probably resides in the Http request.
I got a service that makes an http request to get data from an API:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SequencesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData(){
    return this.http.get("https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/00/sequence?limit=20&page=1");
  }
}
```

Then a component has this code and sends everything to the html document:

```js
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
import {SequencesService} from '../sequences.service';
import {Sequences} from '../sequences';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sequences',
  templateUrl: './sequences.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sequences.component.css']
})
export class SequencesComponent implements OnInit {

  ELEMENT_DATA: Sequences[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Sequence ID', 'Prefix', 'RRC', 'Start Time', 'End Time'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Sequences>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  constructor(private service: SequencesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllSequences();
  }

  public getAllSequences(){
    let resp = this.service.getData();
    resp.subscribe(report => this.dataSource.data = report as Sequences[]);
  }

}
```

This is the html document:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Sequence ID">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sequence ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Prefix">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Prefix </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.prefix}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="RRC">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> RRC </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rRC}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Start Time">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Start Time </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.start}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="End Time">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> End Time </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.end}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try changing "report as Sequences" to "report.json()" where the result would be the array of data items.

Comment: I'm not using *ngFor, i actually copied the code from this video and it works for him https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pk8twkT6esM

Comment: There are multiple possibilities for ths kind of issue: HttpClient is not added in the app.module.ts, to check if there is issue with http you can put a console.log inside sibscribe method and check if data is getting received.

Comment: why not use `resp.subscribe(report => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Sequences>(report as Sequences[]));` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, `report as Sequences[]` is wrong.

Because your required array is nested, in property `items`.

**Second**, there is also an issue with calling the API with parameters.

I've also corrected the API calling at `SequencesService`.

Check out the result at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-rxjs-example-ymtvtf?file=src/app/app.component.ts).